# Assignments just bind names to objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, reference, namespaces

According to the Python tutorial, 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces:

> Assignments do not copy data — they just bind names to objects.

So I'm surprised that the following code doesn't surprise me:

```
>>> a = 42
>>> b = a
>>> b = b / 2
>>> a
42
>>> b
21
```

If the assignment `b = a` just binds the name `b` to the `int` object `42`, which is already bound to `a`, shouldn't `a` be `21` when after `b = b / 2` is executed, since `a` and `b` refer to the same object?

Comment: No, you have **rebound** that name. Integers are immutable. Read this: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Objects don't have names--names have objects.

Comment: @erip You mean an object can have many different names, while a name can only refer to one object?

Comment: @sunqingyao yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you do make another assignment to `b`:

```
b = b / 2
```

and since operations on `int` (immutable) types will **always** return a new object there's no changes made to the original value **whatever** the operation may be.

This differs for mutable types which can change in *certain* operations, namely *augmented assignment* operations were the changes are made in-place:

```
>>> a = [20]
>>> b = a
>>> b += [1]
>>> b
[20, 1]
>>> a 
[20, 1]
```

Note, of course, that this doesn't happen with simple assignments were, as for `int`s the name refers to a new object:

```
>>> b = b + [1]
>>> b
[20, 1, 1]
>>> a
[20, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

after b =b/2, b is new object

```
>>> a = 42
>>> id(a)
8006428
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
8006428
>>> b = b/2
>>> id(b)
8006680
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trace of it:

`>>> a = 42`
a = 42
b is undefined

`>>> b = a`
a = 42
b = a

`>>> b = b / 2`
a = 42
b = 21

The operation `b = b / 2` is creating a new object using `b` which at the time points to `a`.  It is not changing `a`, merely creating a new value by an operation involving `a`.  Now, `b` no longer refers to `a`, but a new value created using `a`.